# postgreSQL DML скрипт с логикой

Tags: postgresql

есть скрипт по обновлению данных(несколько инсертов, апдейтов) и нужно в конец скрипта добавить некую логику которая также будет обновлять данные, но уже с циклами и условиями, как это можно реализовать в постгресе одним скриптом?

```
select distinct name from table
insert into table2 (name) values (name1), (name2), (name3) returning id; в общем все что получил в предыдущем запросе
update table set table2_id = id1; и так для каждого нового имени
```

Comment: А что вам такое невероятное потребовалось, что надо реализовывать циклами ? В SQL 95% всего что только в голову придет реализуется обычными запросами, в postgresql в пределах одного запроса можно сделать вообще все что угодно, включая обновления информации в нескольких таблицах одновременно.

Comment: Но если конечно очень хочется то пишите DO и любой блок кода на PL/SQL https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-do.html

Comment: @Mike дополнил вопрос, это как то возможно реализовать без циклов? и спасибо за ссылку!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одним запросом примерно так:

```
with ins(name, id) as(
  insert into table2 (name)
   select distinct name from table
   returning name, id
)
update table a
   set table2_id=ins.id
  from ins
 where a.name=ins.name
```

При желании, несколько запросов insert/update можно вызывать друг за другом, дописывая новые блоки with, которые используют результаты, полученные в предыдущих блоках with.